# Sketch complex inequalities

Tags: complex-numbers

### Problem

Sketch complex inequalities to complex plane.

(a)$$|z-2i|<1 $$

(b) $$ |z-1-2i|>3 $$

### Attempt to solve

My intuition would tell me that (a) is area inside circle and (b) is area outside of circle in complex plane. However if i try to explicitly solve these inequalities i get answer that doesn't make any sense to me.

I tried with simplified version without inequality ( should contain only points from rim of the circle )

I form expression for length of the radius with Pythagoras.

$$|z|=\sqrt{(\operatorname{Re}(z)^2+(\operatorname{Im}(z))^2}$$
$$ \sqrt{z^2+(-2)^2}=1 $$
$$ z^2+4=1 $$
$$ z^2=-3 $$
$$ z=\pm \sqrt{-3} = \pm i\sqrt{3} $$

I tried to solve where this circles radius is exactly 1. It would seem there is gap in my intuition and cant seem to make sense of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  $$|z-2i|<1$$ you are looking for all points in the  complex plane  whose distance from $2i$ is less that $1$.

That is the open disk centered at $z=2i$ and radius $1$
With center at $(0,2) $and radius $1$ we get $$ x^2+(y-2)^2<1$$

For $$|z-1-2i|>3$$ you are looking for all the points in complex plane whose distance from $ 1+2i$ is greater than $3$.

That  is the outside region of the disk with center $(1,2)$ and radius $3$
You can write the inequality to describe it.

Comment: There is  atypo for the first one centered at $z=2i$. Sorry but also in that case your answer seems not completely related to the OP is asking for that is a clarification to how formalize explicitely the intuition of the result.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one by $z=x+iy$ we have

$$|z-2i|<1 \iff |z-2i|^2<1\iff x^2+(y-2)^2<1$$

and for the second one

$$|z-1-2i|>3\iff |z-1-2i|^2>9\iff (x-1)^2+(y-2)^2>9$$

Answer (score 1):

@Tuki, your intuition is excellent, the formula for $|z|$ as well, but you applied it wrongly, $Re (z-2i) \neq z.$

If you prefer to continue on your own, replace $z$ by $x+iy.$